# Convert SAML 2.0 to JWT while redirecting from /saml/sso

Tags: spring, jwt, saml-2.0, spring-saml

I have a requirement to create a service provider form ADFS IDP. IDP is sending a SAML 2.0 token and in service side I am receiving it.
I have used spring security same extension plugin in service provider.

My code’s flow is mentioned below

/saml/login ——> will make a call to ADFS(IDP)———>redirect to saml/sso (with SAML token)

Now from this same/sso redirection to Front end (client will happen, which requested the token). I want to send back JWT instead of SAML to send back to browser.
What will be the best way to do it. How can I make /saml/sso to covert SAML to JWT in successRedirectHandler.

Sample handler

@Bean

```
public SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler successRedirectHandler() {

    SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler successRedirectHandler =

            new SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler();

    successRedirectHandler.setDefaultTargetUrl("/landing");

    return successRedirectHandler;

}
```

Please note that I am using Nimbus JSON JWT jar for SAML to JWT conversion. I would prefer not to create a separate controller to convert SAML to JWT. Any help and pointers will be helpful.

Comment: @Vladimír Schäfer

Answer (score 0):

Basically, after the authentication on the IDP side, you'll receive the assertions in response. You'll extract the attributes and perform some validation on the service side. You'll create JWT token with desired attributes. After that, you can redirect to target url with the token. Below is a snippet of code.

```
public class SAMLLoginSuccessHandler extends SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

  public SAMLLoginSuccessHandler() {}

  @Override
  public void onAuthenticationSuccess(final HttpServletRequest request,
      final HttpServletResponse response, final Authentication authentication)
      throws IOException, ServletException {

    if (authentication.getPrincipal() instanceof UserDetails
        || authentication.getDetails() instanceof UserDetails) {
      UserDetails details;
      String failureRedirectUrl = Constants.REDIRECTION_WEB;
      if (authentication.getPrincipal() instanceof UserDetails) {
        details = (UserDetails) authentication.getPrincipal();
      } else {
        details = (UserDetails) authentication.getDetails();
      }

      String username = details.getUsername();
      SAMLCredential credential = (SAMLCredential) authentication.getCredentials();
      List<Attribute> attributes = credential.getAttributes();
      // validate user related information coming in assertions from IDP

      // TODO:JWT Token generation code 

      // eventually you want to send that code to client therefore append the token
      // in the url to which you want to redirect
      String redirectUri;  // set the redirect uri  
      response.sendRedirect(redirectUri);
    }
    super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
  }
}
```